# Merged TIFF turned has black background (white in individual TIFFs)

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, black

I downloaded GeoTIFF tiles (multi-channel band). In QGIS I used GDAL --> Raster Miscellaneous --> Merge.

In the merging tool I used my downloaded TIFFs as input. I changed nothing else. The output is now a black TIFF.

[image: black tiff]

In the original individual TIFFs the background is white. What is going on? Can I change it from here to white?

Comment: I know that a similar quewstion exists. Nevertheless, I have no idea how to change a code, I don't use python. Is there a way to change the backgrou without coding?

Comment: You can use QGIS to make the colors anything you want to.  Here is some help on symbolizing rasters with QGIS:  https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/changing_symbology.html